# Передача массива в функцию. C++

Tags: c++

Насколько я знаю, если вызвать `int array[500]` например в `std::cout << array;`, то я получу адрес первого элемента массива. Соотвественно `std::cout << *array;` выведет значение первого элемента. Когда я отправляю в функцию `void foo (int *array){}` Тут я получается говорю, что нужно принять адрес? А не первый элемент массива. 
P.S как получается так, что мы отправляем адрес первого элемента массива, а при этом можем работатЬ со всем массивом в функций `foo`

Comment: Адрес массива совпадает с адресом первого элемента массива. адрес второго элемета = адрес массива + размер элемента. Массивы в памяти - непрерывная область записи переменных друг за другом =) в этом их отличие от списков\деревьев

Comment: как получается так, что мы отправляем адрес первого элемента массива, а при этом можем работатЬ со всем массивом в функций foo

Comment: К этому указателя можно добавить +1, и уже получить второй элемент массива(под индексом 1), если вы конечно об этом спрашиваете

Comment: все остальные элементы следуют за первым

Comment: Массив - ни что иное как просто кусок памяти, в нем ваши переменные идут друг за другом, поэтому не важно что вы передали, массив или ссылку на участок памяти, нужно лишь знать какого размера элементы там хранятся.

Comment: @Fqqlt в смысле просто `int *ptr = array` и чтобы получить следующий элемент просто `*ptr++`. Я походу чего то не понял, потому что для меня это сверьхестественно

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Так получается же, что я передал в функцию адрес первого элемента массива. Ведь так? Так я если передал, как функция узнает, сколько элементов естЬ после первого элемента в массиве

Comment: Функция никак не узнает длину, её надо передавать отдельным аргументом

Comment: @PavelGridin  Я там исправил. Поставил оператор разыменования

Comment: @PavelGridin Походу дошло. А можно вопрос насчет оператора []? Как он работает, на сайтах спрашивают только про перегрузку, а сам по себе как он работает. Ведь если я отправляю в функцию адрес на первый элемент массива я же все равно могу использовать `ptr[]`

Comment: Когда вы нашли первое слово  цитаты, вы можете читать всю цитату. Ничего сверхестественного в этом нет, наоборот, все очень даже естественно

Comment: array[5] эквивалентен *(array+ 5)

Answer (score 2):

По адресу первого элемента массива можно получить адрес второго, третьего и остальных элементов массива. Это называется *адресной арифметикой*. Поэтому получая в функции указатель на первый элемент массива мы можем внутри этой функции получить доступ и к остальным элементам массива.

Реализации языка С++ имеют право придерживаться целого набора относительно сложных правил, объясняющих, какие указатели разрешается формировать на основе каких других указателей (через адресную арифметику). Ответы на такие вопросы могут существенно влиять на оптимизацию кода. Получать указатель на элемент массива из указателя на другой элемент этого же массива - это разрешенное действие.

Answer (score 1):

Это основы си, изложенные Керниганом и Ричи. Причём не сразу понял, что когда вызываешь функцию, передавая массив не с помощью звёздочки, а с помощью квадратных скобок с размером массива в них, происходит то же самое, на стеке ничего не выделяется свыше размера указателя на первый элемент. До сих пор возмущаюсь, зачем тогда писать размер в квадратных скобках?

Comment: Размер массива в аргументах в основном пишут *для других программистов* (рассматривайте это как своего рода комментарий), хотя это и можно использовать в sizeof и т.п.

Comment: Какой сайзоф указателя?! Да объяснили уже тогда, но возмущение не проходит -- я же серьёзно думал, что таким способом массив передаётся через стек, а не один указатель.

Comment: да sizeof покажет размер указателя, то есть 4 или 8

Comment: @PavelGridin или 2 или больше =) привыкните что архитектуры бывают не только x32 и x64 =)

Comment: спасибо за полезный совет, буду привыкать

Comment: Я писал о sizeof  не указателя (разумеется), а массива. `#define N 10
size_t f (int arr[N]) {
typedef int A[N];
 return sizeof(A);
}` -- попробуйте

Comment: Одно время была мода спрашивать на собеседованиях о размере класса на плюсах с виртуальными функциями. Оно понятно, не каждому дано знать о том, что там ещё неявно содержится указатель на адрес с таблицей этих самых функций. А здесь есть такие, кто слышал о ремиконтах-ломиконтах, у которых всего шестнадцать ка памяти было, их использовали в асу тп, потому что в персоналки столько плат типа рс 232 не вставишь и тогда не хватало скорострельности для реального времени, персоналки лишь задавали главное и отображали собранное?